# Making autosuggest list all of the items when you click on its textbox

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use [this plugin](http://react-autosuggest.js.org/) to be able to list all items when we click on the textbox as well as do basic autocomplete functions. It doesn't seem to be able to do this however unless I am wrong.

http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/LGNJMy

```
function getSuggestions(value) {
  const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

  if (escapedValue === '') {
    return languages;
  }

  const regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedValue, 'i');

  return languages.filter(language => regex.test(language.name));
}
```

I tried to use the above, but it doesn't work and I am unsure if it having the full list would allow me to properly implement it as I would need to make the list appear upon an `onClick` event. Is there any way to make this work, or is there a better plugin for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/pRmXQG?editors=0010) which has Autosuggests that show suggestions when textbox is focused which is what you want if I'm not wrong.

Basically `shouldRenderSuggestions` prop is the way to do that.